# resizing of main content and left navigation automatically

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement resizing functionality of main content and left navigation automatically from existing application.. I have copied their html's and js's/css's... but while trying to render I am getting this issue.. any idea?

My code below, I am getting error in ,

```
$("#history").css("left",$("#header-item-history").position().left-80);
```

error is,

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined**

```
function resizeHandler() {

$("#history").css("left",$("#header-item-history").position().left-80);

$("#history").css("height","auto");
if($("#history").height()>($(document).height()-100)) {
    $("#history").css("height",$(document).height()-100);
}

$("#content").css("height",$(window).height()-50);
$("#content-scroll").css("height",$("#content-scroll").parent().height()-50);

$("#header-right").width($(document).width() - $("#header-item-history").position().left - 50);
if($("#header-right").width()<300) {
    $("#header-logged-in-name").css("display","none");
} else {
    $("#header-logged-in-name").css("display","inline-block");
}

/* PROCESS BOX POSITIONING */
$(".process-wrapper").each(function() {
    $(this).css("width",$(this).parent().width()-0);
});

// find best fit for width
var processWrapperWidth = $(".process-wrapper").parent().width();
if(processWrapperWidth<1200) {
    processBoxesVisible = 3;
} else if(processWrapperWidth<1500) {
    processBoxesVisible = 4;
} else if(processWrapperWidth>=1500) {
    processBoxesVisible = 5;
}
processWidth = ($(".process-wrapper").width()/processBoxesVisible)-3;
$(".process").css("width",processWidth);

$(".process-scroll").css("margin-left",0-((processWidth+5) * (processPosition - 1)));

pushEnoughBoxesToFitWidth();

updateProcessBoxTracker();

/***************************/

contentScroll.reinitialise();
```

}

Comment: make sure element with id `header-item-history` exists

Comment: `console.log($("#header-item-history"))`, if there is `[]`.. there is no element with this id..

Comment: this got fixed.. thanks Filburt :)